# Symfony use setter for Arraycollection in CreateController

Tags: symfony, foreach, setter, arraycollection

I'd like to create an upload form for documents. 
It's possible to select several so called 'agencies' and each of these agencies belongs to one specific market.
What I want to do is, set the markets automatically. 
So in my controller I had something like this:

```
$document->setMarket($document->getAgencies()->getMarket());
```

But since the agencies are an ArrayCollection, I can't call a getter on them. So I was thinking about a for each loop in order to get the markets for every single agency. Would that work and if yes how would I do it best and most efficiently?

Would be happy about tips and tricks :D

Comment: Don't understand. You want to set the document market, but for each agency, the market can be different.

Comment: No, I set the agency and the agency is linnked to a market. So each agency has one market and one market can have several agencies. In my form I only select agencies and then want the markets automatically be set, too!

Comment: The design seems flawed here. Do ALL Agencies of a document belong to ONE market?

Comment: No, there are several markets (7) and way more agencies. so several agencies for one market

Comment: Show the code, please.

Comment: I've asked a new question to that, which contains that question, too and shows code!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45983542/symfony-add-data-to-object-on-pre-persist